# How can I add a batch file to the Windows context menu, which on selection runs from that location as admin?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10, contextmenu

I use this batch file to recursively create firewall rules for all files within a particular folder. For it to work, you need to copy it into a particular Windows directory then run the batch file as administrator.

> To be clear I did not create this batch file, it was created by
>   Charles de Havilland.

**Batch File:**

```
@echo off
REM      BATCH FILE CREATED BY CHARLES DE HAVILLAND 10/09/2015
REM  https://sites.google.com/site/mytools4000/home/allow-block-multiple-programs-through-windows-7-firewall
cls
net session >nul 2>&1
    if %errorLevel% == 0 (
        echo.
    ) else (
        GOTO :NOPERM
    )
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)
@cd /d "%~dp0"
for %%* in (.) do set RULENAME=%%~nx*
ECHO|set /p ="- Add "
call :ColorText 0a "Block In & Out "
ECHO  Firewall rules for all *.exe ^& *.dll files
ECHO.
ECHO|set /p = "- located at '"
  call :ColorText 0b "%CD%'" 
ECHO  (inc subfolders)
ECHO.
ECHO|set /p = "- creating "
  call :ColorText 1b "%RULENAME%"
ECHO  as the Firewall rule name ?
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO Press any key to continue  or  CTRL+C to terminate now ...
pause >nul
cls
Echo.
FOR /r %%G in ("*.exe") Do (@echo %%G
NETSH advfirewall firewall add rule name="%RULENAME%-%%~nxG" dir=in program="%%G" action="block" enable="yes")
FOR /r %%G in ("*.exe") Do (@echo %%G
NETSH advfirewall firewall add rule name="%RULENAME%-%%~nxG" dir=out program="%%G" action="block" enable="yes")
FOR /r %%G in ("*.dll") Do (@echo %%G
NETSH advfirewall firewall add rule name="%RULENAME%-%%~nxG" dir=in program="%%G" action="block" enable="yes")
FOR /r %%G in ("*.dll") Do (@echo %%G
NETSH advfirewall firewall add rule name="%RULENAME%-%%~nxG" dir=out program="%%G" action="block" enable="yes")
Echo.
  call :ColorText 0a "done"
ECHO|set /p =" ... Goodbye"
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO Press a key to exit ...
pause >nul
goto :eof

:ColorText
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1
goto :eof

:Finish
Echo.
Echo.
Echo Batch ended...
Goto :END

:NOPERM
ECHO.
ECHO - You must run this file in Administrator mode
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO|SET /p ="- Press any key to exit ..."
Pause >NUL
ECHO   goodbye
ECHO.
ECHO.
:END
```

Is there a way I can automate this process and add it to the explorer context menu, so when I click *start addfwrs.bat* it copies the batch file into the current  folder, runs it as administrator and upon completion deletes itself afterward?

What would you advise?

Comment: So you're expecting somebody to make this script which requires to be run As administrator to be included as a context menu entry for non Administrators, and work based in the current explorer location despite it seemingly being designed as a recurse script?

Comment: There's a reason that Microsoft made it harder to accidentally run administrative tasks without having consciously deciding in that moment that it's the right thing to do. It's called security in depth, and what you want doesn't sound particularly wise, especially considering all the wildcards used in that script. In other words, just don't do it.